# Flutter "demo" stump on application

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am developing application with Flutter and for some reason all the time that some digits (like: 4, %) supposed to appear, a "demo" stump appear insted ([as you can see in the picture bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJxmo.jpg)):

This happen on both debug and release version and both on ios and android

Flutter doctor:

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.17.3, on macOS 11.3.1 20E241, locale en-IL)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Thanx!!

Comment: on terminal type `flutter emulators` check if you have any devices, else create from andoird studio `avd` manager

Answer (score 0):

### update:

The problematic code snippet is this one:

```dart
Text('4.65' ,
     style: TextStyle(
     fontFamily: 'Fontspring-coresansar45',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     fontSize: 12,
     color: ColorConstants.redColor),
     textAlign: TextAlign.center
)
```

Apperntly, font: `'Fontspring-coresansar45'` does not have support for all the numbers and charecters (for example: 4, %)